# NHibernate.Linq - Error querying when Nullable types in Where clause

Tags: vb.net, linq, nhibernate

I have the following NHibernate Linq query:

```
From eachLine In myNhSession.Query(Of SamplePoco)()
     Where eachLine.SampleIntField = 1234
```

The property `SamplePoco.SampleIntField` is type `Nullable(Of Int32)`

When I run the query, I get the following exception:

`System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlCoalesce' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'`

If I change the property type to `Int32`, it works. It seems that Nullable types are automatically converted into a coalesce expression by the Linq compiler.

Debugging the NHibernate, I just found out that this Where clause was converted into: `{where ((eachLine.SampleIntField == 1234) ?? False)}`. As I can understand, the whole condition comparison was translated to be coalesced instead of just the Nullable property.

If I put this way `eachLine.SampleIntField.Equals(1234)` it doesn't work as well ('Equals not implemented' exception)

If I change the query to the following code, it works:

```
From eachLine In myNhSession(Of SamplePoco)()
     Where {1234}.Contains(eachLine.SampleIntField)
```

(not elegant)

Another code that works as well (coalescing the field properly as I was expecting by the first query):

```
From eachLine In myNhSession(Of SamplePoco)()
 Where If(eachLine.SampleIntField,0) = 1234
```

Any suggestions to keep it simple?

Comment: Does `Where eachLine.SampleIntField.HasValue` translate well? You could combine the conditions. Of course this is not simple it the sense of automated.

Comment: Yes, it does. Interestingly, the C# equivalent Linq query works just fine (I've done the test just after posting the question). As a VB.NET  fan against C#, I'm quite disappointed now :(

Comment: That's good! (said the C# addict)

Comment: VB sometimes generates different Expression trees, thats why it happens but that won't help.

Comment: We've stumbed across this and created a re-linq feature request: https://www.re-motion.org/jira/browse/RM-5178
If you think it's an important feature, please check with us on the re-linq mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&pli=1#!forum/re-motion-users

Comment: @Michael Nice! Just voted up this feature request! Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most explicitly clear way to put it, that NHibernate handles, is:

```
From eachLine In myNhSession.Query(Of SamplePoco)()
     Where eachLine.SampleIntField.HasValue AndAlso eachLine.SampleIntField.Value = 1234
```